# Setting multiple namespaces in an XML with VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, dom, namespaces

I am trying to set multiple namespaces with prefixes to my root element.

I managed partially to do so with `.DocumentElement.setAttribute`:

In excel I am using reference to MicrosoftXML, v6.0.

```vb
Sub ExportAsXML()

    Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set oPI = oXMLDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""")
    Set oRootDeklaracja = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "Deklaracja", "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2013/05/23/eD/KodyCECHKRAJOW/")
    oXMLDoc.appendChild oRootDeklaracja
    oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:kpkd", "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/02/01/eD/KodyPKD/"
    oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:etd", "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/08/24/eD/DefinicjeTypy/"
    oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:tns", "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/"
    oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xsi:schemaLocation", "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/"
    oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    oXMLDoc.InsertBefore oPI, oXMLDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0)

oXMLDoc.Save "test.xml"

End Sub
```

The output of the above is (please also note that the "ns1:" prefix in front of "Deklaracja" element is missing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Deklaracja xmlns="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2013/05/23/eD/KodyCECHKRAJOW/" xmlns:kpkd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/02/01/eD/KodyPKD/" xmlns:etd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/08/24/eD/DefinicjeTypy/" xmlns:tns="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

The result I intend to achieve is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tns:Deklaracja xmlns="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2013/05/23/eD/KodyCECHKRAJOW/" xmlns:kpkd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/02/01/eD/KodyPKD/" xmlns:etd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/08/24/eD/DefinicjeTypy/" xmlns:tns="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/ schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you expect:

```
<tns:Deklaracja xmlns="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2013/05/23/eD/KodyCECHKRAJOW/" >
```

And how you declare the `tns` prefix:

```
oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.setAttribute "xmlns:tns", "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/"
```

And how you create the root node:

```
Set oRootDeklaracja = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "Deklaracja", "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2013/05/23/eD/KodyCECHKRAJOW/")
```

Don't match. These are two different name spaces.

In order to assign a prefix to an element name when creating it the language reference for `createNode` states

> namespaceURI  A string defining the namespace URI. If specified, the
>   node is created in the context of the namespaceURI parameter with the
>   prefix specified on the node name. If the name parameter does not have
>   a prefix, this is treated as the default namespace.

So, change the create node line to something like this:

```
Set oRootDeklaracja = OXMLDoc.createNode( _
      1, "x:Deklaracja", _
      "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2013/05/23/eD/KodyCECHKRAJOW/")
```

Then the result of the code in the question becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:Deklaracja xmlns:x="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2013/05/23/eD/KodyCECHKRAJOW/" xmlns:kpkd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/02/01/eD/KodyPKD/" xmlns:etd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/08/24/eD/DefinicjeTypy/" xmlns:tns="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

I leave it up to you to decide how to sort out the prefixes and the URIs...

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the correct namespace when creating your root element. Try this:

```
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict.Add "xmlns"     , "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2013/05/23/eD/KodyCECHKRAJOW/"
    dict.Add "xmlns:kpkd", "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/02/01/eD/KodyPKD/"
    dict.Add "xmlns:etd" , "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/08/24/eD/DefinicjeTypy/"
    dict.Add "xmlns:tns" , "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/"
    dict.Add "xsi:schemaLocation", "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2019/08/07/8334/schema.xsd"
    dict.Add "xmlns:xsi" , "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")    
Set dek = xmlDoc.createNode(1, "tns:Deklaracja", dict("xmlns:tns"))
    dek.setAttribute "xmlns", dict("xmlns")
    dek.setAttribute "xmlns:kpkd", dict("xmlns:kpkd")
    dek.setAttribute "xmlns:etd", dict("xmlns:etd")
    dek.setAttribute "xsi:schemaLocation", dict("xsi:schemaLocation")
    dek.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", dict("xmlns:xsi")
```

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity (I am an absolute newbie), what is the advantage of using dictionaries instead of for example just an array in this case?

Comment: I understand you're going to create several elements to build your XML; in that case would be useful to have all namespaces in a easy to use structure, as a dictionary. Or maybe constants.

Comment: Further question - it seems that .setatribute method is not supported. Is there a workaround for that?